# Does the Square app have a custom URL scheme?

Tags: ios, square, custom-url

In my iOS app, as part of the mobile payments options, I'd like to direct users who have the Square app installed on their device to use this as a payment option.

Is there a custom URL scheme that Square uses that would allow me to launch their app from within mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Square app does have a custom URL schema you can call: **`square://`**

You can also see if the application is installed by the following method:

```
- (BOOL)isSquareInstalled 
{ 
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"square://"]]; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass information using that URL? For instance, can I pass in the name of the client to bill with a product/pricing list?

Comment: Thats a good question @mbm30075, I am not aware of the data structure but you could possible contact their support to see if you could get some docs on passing that info to the app.

Answer (score 2):

The Square Pay app uses the URL Scheme square-pay://